# Draw a view in canvas

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas

I have a viewpager with multiple pages. I have to show the selector *yellow circle*. Is it possible to draw the complete view using canvas?

[image]

Comment: Refer this link https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator/tree/master/library/src/com/viewpagerindicator

Answer (score 0):

I would use shapes to draw the circles. Like that:

`<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >
    <solid android:color="@color/yeallow"/>
</shape>`

You could create a view and use its shape as background.

And if you want a view pager behaviour, you could put together a bunch of circles inside a Linear layout and change them according to the view pager`s page.

Comment: I know i can draw circle using `GradientDrawable`